# Как сделать разграничительные полосы между рядами в таблице?

Tags: html, css, table

Есть таблица, в которой хочу сделать разделительные полосы между рядами за исключением последнего. Как есть сделать правильно? Можно назначить границы `td`, но как исключить тогда последний ряд? [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/1723/)

```css
#codexpl th,
#codexpl td {
  padding: 0.8em;
}

#codexpl th {
  background-color: #6699FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
}

tr:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}

tr:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="codexpl">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Columna</th>
    <th>Relative</th>
    <th>Isso</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Is</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>not equals</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>the</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>real</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#codexpl th,
#codexpl td {
  padding: 0.8em;
}
#codexpl th{
  border: 0.4em solid #fff;
}

#codexpl th {
  background-color: #6699FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:first-child ~ tr td{
  border-top: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<table id="codexpl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Columna</th>
      <th>Relative</th>
      <th>Isso</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>This</td>
      <td>Column</td>
      <td>Is</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Coloumn</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>not equals</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>the</td>
      <td>Column</td>
      <td>real</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>first</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Coloumn</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```